# How do I add a georeferenced JPEG with a JGW Worldfile to OpenLayers v5.3.0?

Tags: openlayers, openstreetmap

I have a JPEG file with an associated .JGW worldfile containing the following data:

```
0.0144218
0
0
-0.0144218
-65758.8265181
-130841.5565499
```

My Jpeg is `21177*14242` pixels resolution.

I'm currently working with the following code:

```
let extent = [0, 0, 0, 0,]; //I need the correct values!

let exampleProjection = new ol.proj.Projection({
code: 'orto-image',
units: 'pixels',
extent: extent //I need the correct values!
});

let exampleImageSource = new ol.source.ImageStatic({
url: "https://mywebsite.com/uploads/example.jpg",
projection: exampleProjection,
imageExtent: extent //I need the correct values!
});

let exampleImageLayer = new ol.layer.Image({
source: exampleImageSource 
});
```

I would like to present this image over my OSM map. How can this be achieved?

Comment: Use those values and the jpeg dimensions in pixels to calculate the `imageExtent` for an `ol.source.ImageStatic` The formulae needed can be found here http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/manage-data/raster-and-images/world-files-for-raster-datasets.htm

Comment: The link is great but I'm still not quite sure how convert the values. I updated the post with the resolution if you can show me how.

Answer (score 1):

Those values would give

```
left = -65758.8265181
top = -130841.5565499
right = -65758.8265181 + 0.0144218*21177 = -65453.4160595
bottom = -130841.5565499 - 0.0144218*14242 = -131046.9518255

extent = [-65758.8265181, -131046.9518255, -65453.4160595, -130841.5565499]
```

I don't know what projection that would be in, or if OpenLayers and/or the browser could handle a 300 megapixel image.

Comment: Thank you Mike I will try this tomorrow and write down the formula if it works.